# EditText caches old text

Tags: java, android

I have following issue. I have EditText and TextWatcher which format input text according to some rules. In method afterTextChanged() I format it. Then I have formatted string and I want to replace old value of EditText by formatted value. 
Next we have two options:

1. use EditText.setText()
2. use Editable.replace()

If we use first option, EditText works very slowly and looses symbols.
But If we use second method, Editable doesn't replace old text, but append new text to old text.

Maybe someone had similar issue?

Upd: using Editable.clear() then Editable.append() or insert() have similar effect

Code:

```
    public static class LoginWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private EditText target;
    private LoginFilter loginFilter = new LoginFilter();

    private int lastLength;
    private boolean wasPhoneNumber = false;

    private AsYouTypeFormatter formatter;
    private boolean isFormattingStopped;

    public LoginWatcher(OnLoginEnterListener onLoginInputListener, EditText target) {
        listener = onLoginInputListener;
        this.target = target;
        lastLength = target.getText().length();
        formatter = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().getAsYouTypeFormatter(Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (isFormattingStopped) {
            return;
        }

        if (count > 0 && hasSeparator(s, start, count)) {
            stopFormatting();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        target.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        boolean isSymbolsChecked = loginFilter.check(s.toString());
        boolean isEmail = StringUtils.isEmailValid(s.toString());
        boolean isPhoneNumber = isPhoneNumber(s.toString());



        if (lastLength <= s.length()) {
            if (isPhoneNumber && !isFormattingStopped) {
                String formatted = reformat(s, Selection.getSelectionEnd(s));
                if (formatted != null) {
                    target.setText(formatted);
                    target.setSelection(target.getText().length());
                }

            } else if (wasPhoneNumber) {
                String unformatted = unFormatPhoneNumber(s.toString());

                target.setText(unformatted); // or s.clear(); s.append(); 
                target.setSelection(target.getText().length());
            }
        }

        lastLength = s.length();
        wasPhoneNumber = isPhoneNumber;

        if (isFormattingStopped) {
            isFormattingStopped = s.length() != 0;
        }

        target.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    private String unFormatPhoneNumber(String s) {

        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

        if (s.isEmpty()) {
            return s;
        }

        if (chars[0] == '+') {
            boolean isPhoneNumber = true;
            for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; ++i) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(chars[i])) {
                    isPhoneNumber = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPhoneNumber) {
                return s;
            }
        }

        return s.replaceAll("[\\+\\(\\)\\s\\-]+", "");
    }

    private String reformat(CharSequence s, int cursor) {
        int curIndex = cursor - 1;
        String formatted = null;
        formatter.clear();
        char lastNonSeparator = 0;
        boolean hasCursor = false;
        int len = s.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (PhoneNumberUtils.isNonSeparator(c)) {
                if (lastNonSeparator != 0) {
                    formatted = getFormattedNumber(lastNonSeparator, hasCursor);
                    hasCursor = false;
                }
                lastNonSeparator = c;
            }
            if (i == curIndex) {
                hasCursor = true;
            }
        }
        if (lastNonSeparator != 0) {
            formatted = getFormattedNumber(lastNonSeparator, hasCursor);
        }
        return formatted;
    }

    private String getFormattedNumber(char lastNonSeparator, boolean hasCursor) {
        return hasCursor ? formatter.inputDigitAndRememberPosition(lastNonSeparator)
                         : formatter.inputDigit(lastNonSeparator);
    }

    private boolean isPhoneNumber(String s) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(s) && Patterns.PHONE.matcher(s).matches();
    }

    private boolean hasSeparator(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count) {
        for (int i = start; i < start + count; i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (!PhoneNumberUtils.isNonSeparator(c)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void stopFormatting() {
        isFormattingStopped = true;
        formatter.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I think you need to call setText and related methods on the editable instance instead of on the textField.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the methods provided by [Editable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        target.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        boolean isSymbolsChecked = loginFilter.check(s.toString());
        boolean isEmail = StringUtils.isEmailValid(s.toString());
        boolean isPhoneNumber = isPhoneNumber(s.toString());

        if (lastLength <= s.length()) {
            if (isPhoneNumber && !isFormattingStopped) {
                String formatted = reformat(s, Selection.getSelectionEnd(s));
                if (formatted != null) {
                    s.replace(0, s.length(), formatted)
                    target.setSelection(formatted.length());
                }

            } else if (wasPhoneNumber) {
                String unformatted = unFormatPhoneNumber(s.toString());

                s.replace(0, s.length(), formatted)
                target.setSelection(formatted.length());
            }
        }

        lastLength = s.length();
        wasPhoneNumber = isPhoneNumber;

        if (isFormattingStopped) {
            isFormattingStopped = s.length() != 0;
        }

        target.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
```